# Add disk space to the OS drive without raid

Tags: windows, partitioning, raid, raid-0

I have 2x40GB SSDs. When I install my Windows on the first drive, after a while I start to get the "Low disk space" messages. My mainboard doesn't have a RAID controller and since it's new, I don't want to buy a new one. I looked around and couldn't find a suitable RAID controller to buy.
I was wondering if there is a way to install the OS and after the first run, somehow append the disk space of my 2nd SSD and make it a 1x80GB drive. Is there a software solution for this?

For the record, I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: There is a way to do it, it is called spanning, but I am not sure how to accomplish this as I have never had to do it...

Comment: Off main question: Be sure to turn off Windows "System Protection".  In 7 it's under the Control Panel > System & Security > System > System Protection.  That sucks up space.

Comment: @nerdwaller It was off anyway but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it, it is called spanning, but I am not sure how to accomplish this as I have never had to do it...

Here is a site that detials the process, hopefully this helps... I don't think it will matter if it is Windows 7, or 8 as the process should be fairly similar.

http://mintywhite.com/vista/span-volumes-widows-drives/

Comment: Thanks. At the end of the article it says that it will format the drives. Do you know whether it is possible to install the OS on such drive? I mean, I can hit "Shift+F10", create a span drive before installing the OS but is it going to boot up?

Comment: I don't know, like I said I have never done it before... anyone else know?

Comment: OK. I'll wait to see if anyone else has tried it but if not, I'm choosing this as the answer since this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount drives as folders on your C drive. Catch is, files will have to be moved to that folder to save any space. You can do this in the drive manager

Comment: This won't help. Many programs install files on `C:` and I have to run tons of registry modifications to make it work. It just doesn't worth it.